# $f^{(n)}(x)>0$ for all $n$ implies $1/f(x)$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I was wondering if it is true that if for $f:[0,\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$

$$\frac{{\rm d}^n}{{\rm d}x^n} \, f(x) > 0 \qquad \forall n \geq 0$$

then $1/f(x)$ is convex. It is not true if the interval defined above would be finite as can be seen from examples like $\frac{1}{1-x}$ or $-\log(1-x)$, but it seems different as soon as the interval is infinite.

Comment: why do you say it's not true for $1/(1-x)?$ Here $1/f(x)=1-x,$ which is convex

Comment: @zhw. That has a singularity at $x=1$. OP has the domain $[0, \infty]$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 My interpretation is that the OP said if $[0,\infty)$ is replaced by a finite interval it won't work on the finite interval.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Let $g(x)=e^{x^{2}}$. Then all derivatives of $g$ are non -negative.  Computing the second derivative we see that  $\frac 1 g=e^{-x^{2}}$ is concave on $(0,\frac 1 {\sqrt 2})$ and convex on $(\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}, \infty)$. Now let $n \in \mathbb N$ and consider $f(x)=\frac  1n e^{x}+g(x)$. All derivatives of this function are strictly positive. If $\frac  1 f$ is convex for each $n$ the  so would $\frac  1 g$ be.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I already posted a counterexample ($f(x)=a+{\rm e}^{bx}$ for $a$ sufficiently large) on a previous answer, but it was deleted. It was a stupid question.